# Flexible layout for Mobile

Tags: javascript, webkit, css

Usually i need to develop the mobile website for different platforms, like iphone 3 and 4, andriod, Blackberry torch etc.

I generally sliced images depending on the platform. My problem is, all the time i need to slice images for different devices to render good quality images. But i want to use only one set of images and want to cater to all devices with out impacting the image quality.

Please suggest if any one has a better solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use one set of images for all screen resolutions, then I suggest you read up on responsive web design and fluid images.
There are ways to let your images stretch (and retract) with the screen resolutions that will offer a great experience for any resolution.

There is a great article by Ethan Marcotte on [responsive web design here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

He also wrote an article specifically on [fluid images here](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider http://tinysrc.net/